# Oracle recovery problem

Tags: oracle, recover

I execute the following command and the error occurs:

```
recover database until time '2009-01-09 12:26';
ORA-00283: recovery session canceled due to errors
ORA-19907: recovery time or SCN does not belong to recovered incarnation;
```

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You need to add what database type and what command you are executing, the question is too vague to answer.

Answer (score 1):

There's a suggested action [here](http://ora-19907.ora-code.com/)

I'm not an Oracle user, so that's as far as I can go.  [Just Googling the code](http://tinyurl.com/8tc45m) found that though.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say if you're trying this recovery on the original "in-place" database or on a restored copy somewhere else.  Some of your options depend on which situation applies.

One quick thing to do to give yourself some direction is to startup and mount the database and then issue a "recover database until cancel"  (optionally specifying "using backup controlfile" if you restored a controlfile as part of the restore).  Then examine the details (time and change# ) of the first archive log that Oracle asks you to apply.  Compare that to the information in the V$DATABASE view - remember that you can query the V$ views in the mounted state.